# Sharing encryption/decryption key between applications

Tags: java, android, encryption, android-keystore, android-security

I have 3 Android apps

1. **App1** encrypts the file and stores it to an external storage
   (generates key and iv and stores those byte[] to external storage
   too)
2. **App2** has hard coded paths to key and iv, so it can decrypt the file.
3. **App3** doesn't have those paths, so it generates new iv and key and
   gets some garbage content when tries to encrypt the file.

My question is: how can I share iv and key between App1 and App2 more securely - not saving files to external storage and hard coding paths to them in the second app?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve / what is the business goal of the file sharing?

Comment: You need to first have a way to trust the device you want to share the key with, and that device needs to have a device specific key pair that is trusted to be part of it. Then you can encrypt with the public key of the pair, or you can establish a secure path to the device with it.

Comment: Applications are on the same device. I want to show that I can securely share data between apps App1 and App2 by encrypting the data and sharing the key between those two apps, but App3 that doesn't have the key even if it can access the file content of encrypted file (it is saved to the external storage) it can't access original file content as it doesn't have the key.

Comment: @Mediha Got any solution?